# How do I convert images from base 64 to their file types in PHP?

Tags: php, png, jpeg, gif, bmp

I have objects containing images as base 64 strings, the object also contains file names for the images, and file types (jpeg, png, gif & bmp) for the images.
The base 64 strings have already had the tags (e.g. "data:image/png;base64" removed from the beginning.

The format for the objects ($myImg) are as follows:

- $myImg->fileName contains the name that the converted image should be saved under.
- $myImg->fileType describes the format that the file is supposed to be saved as - this is used to specify the path extension in the fopen() function.
- $myImg->b64 contains the 64 bit binary string which represents the image.

The code for my function is as folows:

```
function toImg(ImageString $myImg){
    //Output file is in the same directory as the PHP script.
    //Uses the object's filetype attribute as the file extension.
    $outputFile = fopen($myImg->fileName . "." . $myImg->fileType, "w");
    $image = base64_decode($myImg->b64);
    fwrite($outputFile, $image);
    fclose($outputFile);
}
```

The function creates the image files, but I get errors when trying to view them in Xubuntu Image Viewer. The errors are as follows:

- Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x14 0x00)
- Fatal error reading PNG image file: not a PNG file.
- File does not appear to be a GIF file.
- BMP image has bogus header data.

I've looked through and followed guides for base64 to image conversion, but none of them have encountered these errors.

Comment: That should work, if the base64 data is valid image content. Where do you get that object from? How is it populated?

Comment: The image Dat was retrieved from an XML file output from an MS Access database.

Comment: What happens if you try to show the image in base 64 format in the browser with an `<img>`-tag (with the `data:image/png;base64,` prepended (changing png with the correct file type, of course)? Does it work then?

Comment: The image shows as broken when it's opened in my browser. I'm assuming that means that the base 64 strings are invalid.

Comment: If you added the base64 string correctly: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,the-bade64-string" />` then yes.

Comment: Yeah, it's broken. Thanks for your help. If you post this as an answer, I can mark you as solving it.

Comment: Bummer... I added my suggestion and conclusion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to show the image inline in the browser, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,the-base64-string" />
```

*(change `png` to the correct image format)*

If the image is still broken, then the image data is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the image from base64 like this:

```
function base64_to_jpeg_img($base64_img_string, $output_img) {
    $input_file_open = fopen($output_img, "wb"); 

    $data = explode(',', $base64_img_string);
    fwrite($input_file_open, base64_decode($data[1])); 
    fclose($input_file_open); 

    return $output_img; 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: He wrote that the `data:image/png;base64` etc already was stripped away from the bas64 string (which is basically what your explode is trying to do).